# Is there a submit handler for custom fields?

Tags: 7, entities

I built a custom field, and now I'm adding an image upload to that custom field.  The type is managed_file.  When the user saves the content, where can I handle the file after submit?

Comment: Would hook_field_storage_pre_update() be the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [hook_field_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_update/7) in your module where you define your field..

> Define custom update behavior for this module's field data.
>
> This hook is invoked from field_attach_update() on the module that
>   defines a field, during the process of updating an entity object
>   (node, taxonomy term, etc.). It is invoked just before the data for
>   this field on the particular entity object is updated into field
>   storage. Only field modules that are storing or tracking information
>   outside the standard field storage mechanism need to implement this
>   hook.